# Improper integral: $\int_2^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to solve $\int_2^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}\, dx$.
I have read on the web that someone states the following:
since $\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}\leq \frac{1}{x}$ and the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is divergent then the original integral si divergent.
But I disagree since in my opinion if I have $0\leq f\leq g$, if $g$ is integrable then also $f$ it is; but for the divergence this does not hold, right?
Anyway I can't know how to solve the improper integral, can you help me?

Comment: It diverges, just pick the points where $\sin$ equal $1$, thicken this a bit and get a lower bound by the harmonic series.

Comment: MaybeI I have not understood can you write me down the passages please?

Comment: You should consider a small  $\varepsilon>0$ and then the intervalls of the form $\left[\frac{k\pi}{2}-\varepsilon, \frac{k\pi}{2}+\varepsilon\right]$ then you get: $$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}\, dx \ge \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} \int_{\frac{k\pi}{2}-\varepsilon}^{\frac{k\pi}{2}+\varepsilon} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}\, dx \ge \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} \int_{\frac{k\pi}{2}-\varepsilon}^{\frac{k\pi}{2}+\varepsilon} \frac{c}{x}\, dx$$ for a suitable $c>0$… now proceed from here.

Comment: @Gono Thanks but i have not understood a thing: its is right to see $\int_2^\infty=\int_2^{k\pi/2-\epsilon}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int _{k\pi/2-\epsilon}^{k\pi/2+\epsilon}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether an integral is divergent, you need to find a lower bound of the integrand whose integral diverges, i.e. if $\int f$ diverges and $g\geq f\geq 0$, then $\int g$ diverges too (it is the contraposition of your statement on convergent integrals).

The average value of $\sin^2 x$ is $1/2$ so this should give you a hint to get a lower bound. For every integer $k\in\mathbb Z$, you have $\forall x\in[k\pi+\pi/4,k\pi+3\pi/4], \sin^2 x\geq 1/2$. Therefore, you can split your integral this way and get a lower bound that diverges :

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}\mathrm dx \geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{k\pi+3\pi/4}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x}\mathrm dx\geq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{k\pi+3\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm dx}{2x}$$

Using $\frac{1}{2(k+1)\pi}$ as a lower bound of $\frac{1}{2x}$ for $x\in[k\pi+\pi/4,k\pi+3\pi/4]$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{k\pi+3\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm dx}{2x}\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{k\pi+3\pi/4}\frac{\mathrm dx}{2(k+1)\pi}\geq\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4(k+1)}=\infty$$

Therefore, $\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x}\mathrm dx $ diverges.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question: the original integral starts from $2$, now if a rewrite the integral as a series surely the upper limits is stille $\infty$ but the lower limit is $\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\pi}{4}\neq 2$...how can I treat this fact?

Comment: @Nik The part of the integral between $2$ and $\pi+\pi/4$ is bounded below by $0$ and therefore omitted in the sum, as well as the parts between $k\pi+3\pi/4$ and $(k+1)+\pi/4$.

Comment: So it would be $\int_2^\infty=\int_2^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_{k\pi+3\pi/4}^{(k+1)+\pi/4}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k\pi+\pi/4}^{k\pi+3\pi/4}$?

Comment: You forgot the sum for the second term otherwise yes, since all the intervals on the right-hand side add up without overlap to the interval on the left-hand side.

Comment: Oh yes thanks! Last question: I would write also $\int_2^\infty f(t)dt=\int_2^{2\pi}f(t)dt+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi}f(t)dt$ right?

Comment: That's true, however bear in mind that slicing improper integrals require caution as semi-convergent integrals (i.e. convergent but not absolutely convergent) can show different values depending on how you slice them (just like sums).

Comment: But if iI am interested only on the convergence or eventually divergence and not on the specific value of the integral this is a good via?

Comment: Then make sure your bounds are correct.